# Client port changes with each request

Tags: sockets, client

I am trying to establish a TCP/IP connection between a controller (client) and a program in my PC (server) using C++, I used a sniffer to see how client’s requests are being sent and I found out that each connect request from the controller is sent from a different port and known IP, it starts with random port number and increment by 1 with each request till I restart the controller or the server receives the request, I have some questions.

1- Is that a standard behaviour and what is the idea behind this knowing that the controller is a Mitsubishi controller?

2- Is there any way I can get the new port of the controller without using accept?

Comment: Expected behaviour. Think about all of the failure cases that could happen if the client always used the same port number. A simple one is late packets from a previous connection trying to sneak in as legitimate packets for the new connection.

Comment: If the source port were fixed, what would happen when a client tries to make two simultaneous connections to the same server?

Comment: I see, it some how introduces a bug in the code, if the socket is closed for any reason I must force the controller to send a new request or the communication won't be established and this is not available all the time

Comment: TCP is a connection-oriented communication protocol. If the connection is interrupted and lost, the connection must be re-established. Consider UDP instead if you don't want connections or want to manage the connections yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not so much the behaviour of the controller as it is the network stack running on top of the controller and may be integrated into the controller hardware (Search keyword: TCP offload).

1. This is expected behaviour. To prevent all sorts of nasty side effects, a simple example is late packets from a previous connection trying to sneak in as legitimate packets for a later connection, a port is not recycled for reuse for a lengthy period after the socket using the port is closed. Your port may not be available for use. A simple solution is to do exactly what OP's network stack did: sequentially assign the next port number.
2. Not with BSD-style sockets. `accept` accepts a connection with the client. If you do not accept, you don't get a socket to handle the connection and with the socket, you should not care what the port is. It's all abstracted away and hidden out of sight.

If this is a problem, consider using a connectionless protocol like UDP. You don't get automatic re-transmission when packet loss is detected and all of the other nice things TCP does for you, but there is no connection overhead.